# Help with a Video streaming a Meeting and archiving it in HD using 1 camera

Tags: video, streaming

The Setup

Sony Camcorder connected to IMAC via firewire And a PC via Component cable to HDMI on the PC

Imac records Hd video using IMovie and a 2TB Harddrive
Pc Streams using DaCast to Flash encoder to the Genesis website
Audio coming from the Analog Sound board to the camera for the HDVideo on Imovie and to the PC for the stream.

WHat we do. We Record a conference in Hd Video using IMAC and I movie, at the sametime a Diff Pc connected to the Same camera we stream a conference in English and in Spanish to our website.
We use Dacast to broadcast.

The question is.

Can someone please give me some advise on how to improve this set up with the newest tech available?

Comment: What are you asking?  You have a bunch of objectives listed, but no clear single question.

Comment: ok sorry about that. I can see your point. Thanks.

Comment: This is still way, way too broad.  Try asking a single, answerable question per post.  Currently, someone can't give a full answer without knowing the answer to every question and someone having a portion of your problems will have a hard time finding an answer.  Additionally, some of these questions may possibly be considered off topic (they are borderline), while others are firmly on-topic.  Also, be sure to double check the site for existing answers to some of these questions.  They may not match exactly, but we have had some similar questions to a few of these in the past.

Comment: ok i hope that will work. sorry this is my 1st post I have alot to ask so ill take it slow.

Comment: it's still a bit broad, but I think it is answerable now.  No worries about the difficulty.  Writing really useful questions takes a bit of effort and that's why we have comments to be able to discuss the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a video conferencing platform.  Platforms like WebEx, GoToMeeting, Microsoft Lync or Adobe Connect.  All these platforms are designed for handling video feeds from multiple locations along with screen sharing and most of them support reasonable to high quality recordings of the meetings as well.

Several of these platforms also support larger scale conference modes where you have a small number of presenters (that can be at remote locations) but a large number of spectators.